# why the timer doesn't stop in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, timer

can you please help me with this code . i made a timer .

i want the timer stops when it's  value gets 1 ;

but it doesn't  . i don't  know where is the problem.

please help me . thank you.

here is the result in emulator:

[image]

here is my whole code:

```
class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  double progress = 0;
  void startTimer() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (progress == 1) {
          timer.cancel();
        } else {
          progress += 0.1;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(progress.toStringAsFixed(1)),
              SizedBox(
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: progress,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  progress = 0;
                  startTimer();
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Start'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of floating point error. In software development decimals can't be used in calculations with 100% accuracy. You can't guarantee that 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.2. The problem here is that `progress` never will equal 1. If you print `progress` in your else branch of the timer you will see that it shows:

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
1.0999999999999999
1.2
1.3
```

To solve it simply don't check for one but check if it's higher than 0.99 for example so like

```
        if (progress > 0.99) {
          timer.cancel();
        } else {
          progress += 0.1;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

If the timer doesn't stop when its value reaches 1, it might be due to the condition inside the timer's callback not being met exactly due to floating-point arithmetic inaccuracies. When you increment progress by 0.1, it might not reach exactly 1 due to the way floating-point numbers are represented in computer arithmetic. Thus, the condition if (progress == 1) may never be true, causing the timer to not cancel as expected.

A better approach is to check if the progress is greater than or equal to 1. This will ensure that the timer stops even if there's a slight arithmetic inaccuracy. Here's how you can adjust the startTimer method:

```html
void startTimer() {
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    setState(() {
      if (progress >= 1) { // Change this line
        timer.cancel();
      } else {
        progress += 0.1;
        if (progress > 1) { // Ensure progress does not exceed 1
          progress = 1;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

With this adjustment, the timer will cancel as soon as progress is greater than or equal to 1, ensuring that the timer stops. Also, by checking if progress exceeds 1 after incrementing it and setting it back to 1 if it does, you can avoid having a progress value that exceeds the maximum expected value, ensuring that the CircularProgressIndicator behaves as expected.

Comment: Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. I notice that your most recent *questions* are also AI-generated or assisted.  While this is not allowed either, folks are typically more forgiving of that. However, please use your own words in the future.  Thanks!